# Jade puzzle: Forcing whitespace to display to end user (ft. Angular)

Tags: angularjs, whitespace, pug

Jade is a phenomenally clean engine.  Here's a puzzle I've been running into frequently.

My Problem is: Output with no whitespace!!  All the elements just run right into each other.

I'm trying to achieve a few things at the same time:

- English content clean for later i8ln
- No inline  etc. HTML
- Styles in classes
- Angular special modules inline

I'm going to paste multiple versions of the same block of Jade I have written- they all "work" for the end user, and I dislike all of these versions and am ashamed of them all equally.

Please tear them apart and tell me what I'm missing!  Thanks very much.

Nick

### Version 1

What I dislike the most about this is the gross misuse of the `&nbsp;` tag.  This tag *might* be appropriate between the number of votes and the word vote, however I would still prefer to use css white-space for that.

```
h2 {{voteTotalTrue}}&nbsp;
  ng-pluralize(count="votesFor['Joe']", when="{'1':'Vote','other':'Votes'}")
  span &nbsp;for&nbsp;
  span.candidate Joe
```

### Version 2

What I dislike the most about this is that it's brittle.  It works because I've placed whitespace carefully where it will force Jade to preserve it, however it's a fairly standard risk that during i8ln some of these gaps will be overlooked.

```
h2
  span {{voteTotalTrue}}
  ng-pluralize(count="votesFor['Joe']", when="{'1':' Vote','other':' Votes'}")
  span  for
  span.candidate  Joe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force Jade to respect your spaces, explicitly output a string with spaces:

```
span= ' for '
```

That is the easiest way.

dobesv has summarised various whitespace tricks and gotchas with Jade in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dobesv/1223968).

Comment: Oh didn't you have an answer here before?  It's always useful to see alternatives.  ;)

Comment: All else trumped by the ``=' '`` tip at the end of the dobesv gist you cited.  Thanks!!